# Identify this board and card game relating to 19th century race horses

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone know the name of the board game in the picture below please?

[image]

Comment: Orme, Sceptre, Ladas, Jeddah and Hermit appear to be famous horses from the end of the 19th Century.

Comment: Yep it's an old board game we found while going through old boxes of my grandad.

Comment: Is it bad that most things I search for take me right back here, including links to your pic?

Comment: For what it's worth, I skimmed through boardgamegeek's listings for things tagged animals or racing, or with betting mechanics, from before 1930, and didn't find anything promising. There are plenty without pictures or obvious names, though, so could be I missed something. (Also, wow, there are a lot of old steeplechase games!)

Comment: It looks like a very early Ascot game..

Comment: This very much reminds me of the playing card based drinking game Race Horses which uses all the same components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this looks like a version of Minoru. Seems like a very old 19th century board. It would very difficult to actually identify it.

Comment: Based on the [images at boardgamegeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/images/boardgame/24593/minoru) it looks like Minoru is also a horse racing game but it's not the same.

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter, but I assume the reason for the down-vote is because this answer should have been posted as a comment on the question rather than as a full answer, particularly because it is speculation.

Comment: It's close enough to Minoru that it could just be a different publisher's take on the same game.